# Changing a question into a request for advice

Tags: grammar

How can I change a statement like どこへいきますか to mean "Where *should* I go"? Basically, what is the rule for changing a question into a request for advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the following could be used:

> "where should I go?"
>
> どこへ行{い}けばいいですか？
> どこへ行ったらいいですか？
> どこへ行くべきですか？
>
> "where should I go I wonder", sounds a little softer:
>
> どこへ行こうかな？

According to [this blog post](http://blog.hjenglish.com/shichua/articles/933113.html), there isn't a lot of difference in meaning between `良{よ}い` and `いい`, but `良い` gives an impression of being more formal and is more likely to be used in written form and `いい` more likely to be used in spoken form. If in doubt, I think it's best to stick to `いい`.

Comment: どこへ行っていいですか? means 'Where is it ok to go?', which isn't the requested meaning. Using 良い makes it sound very formal.

Comment: @Bathrobe oops, I think you're right about `どこへ行っていいですか`...I've edited my post, thanks!

Comment: どこへ行っていいですかis not natural Japanese. If you want to say 'Where is it OK to go,' it'd be more like 'どこなら行ってもいいですか'/'行ってもいい場所はどこですか'.

Comment: どこへ行っていいです is fine in conversation. It means 'where is it permissible to go'.

Answer (score 2):

I would use どこへ行けばいい？ for 'where should I go?'